# Get server response from NSURLSessionUploadTask using custom delegate

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I would like to upload an image to a server by using `NSURLSessionUploadTask`, which I have already accomplished by using a custom delegate

```
let task =  NSURLSession(
    configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
    delegate: self,
    delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
).uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: data)

task!.resume()
```

But I am unable to get the server's response. Using `task.response` returns the error code and other header information, but does not return the actual html shown on the page.

I can't create the url task with a completion handler, because I need to get the progress of the upload.

How can I get the NSData from a page response using `NSURLSessionUploadTask`?

Comment: Did you implement NSURLSessionTaskDelegate in your class? The delegate methods should be invoked to indicate the progress of upload and also after completion..

Comment: @Subbu The problem is that I'm not sure how to get the server's response. I'm able to get the progress, and I'm able to see when the upload is completed, but I'm unable to see what the server's response html is

Comment: hmm.. may be task.response.data has the info?  did  you want to  convert the data to nsstring and print to see if that is the html..  something like           var datastring = NSString(data:task.response.data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String?

Comment: @Subbu Sadly, theres no `task.response.data`

Comment: My apologies..  Just trying to help, can you try gathering the data in "didReceiveData"  .. [you could have a global NSData instance and append the received data ] .. In 'didCompleteWithError' you can convert the data to string...

Comment: @Subbu Actually, I was wrong. There is a `didReceiveData` method, and it works. Could you please post that in an answer so I can accept it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yay!! i am so glad it worked for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gather the data via `didReceiveData`, and could have a global NSData instance and append the received data.

Then, in `didCompleteWithError`, you can convert the received data to a string to get the response HTML.